# display an image while a page is loading in an iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, css, ajax

I have a website with a menu, when menu item is clicked I display the page for that menu in an iframe(iframe is set to display home page initially by default). sometimes it could take few seconds to display the page for the selected menu item (for example reports) and I would like to display a loading image while the page is loading. how to do this using javascript or jQuery (sample code will be helpful)? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the loading image to the iframe innerHTML ( or to a div and stop using iframe ) , then use ajax to fetch the new page content , on success iframe innerHTML becomes the content fetched by ajax witch overwrites the loading image . easy to setup but i recomend you stop using iframes

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how can a page be loaded into a div without using iframe? what is the reason to not use iframes?

Comment: you can load the page into a div as explained in my answer ( just use a div instead of iframe ) , the reason i say not to use iframes is that the actual page loaded is slightly smaller since you don't need to include all the css/js/<head> html element and so on , just the content insde the html body , it has certan limitations for example you whant to load a page from a site you don't own ... so you can't make the necesary changes to load smaller content then use iframe couse you need the aditional css/js . just a personal preff not to work with iframes

Answer (score 2):

Usually you cannot know when the page finished loading in an iframe. The iframe loading is independent. What you can do is to get the content of the page that you have in the iframe through a ajax get request, and in this way do an animation while you wait for the content.

Answer (score 1):

write a function to show the image and call it when you set the iframe src. when the page is loaded call from within the loaded page a function to hide the image (`parent.HideImage`)
I think the onload event of the iframe is not supported in all browsers